# Adding a table of attribute information onto map

Tags: arcmap, fields-attributes, table

I am using ArcMap.

How can I take a feature's attribute information (i.e buildings) and place the names and building numbers in a table, so that anyone looking at the map can relate the building number on the map to the name on the table?

Comment: By definition, ArcGIS stores attributes in a table. Do you mean a graphic table, on the display canvas with the map?

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search found this Esri documentation:

[Adding a table to a layout](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/adding-a-table-to-a-layout.htm)

From the description on the page:

> When creating a layout, you can display attribute tables on it to help describe the features your map shows. The appearance of the table in the Table window defines how it will look on the layout. Thus, you'll want to set the text font and size before you add the table to the layout. Once added, any additional formatting to the Table window won't affect its display on the layout.
>
> You determine which rows and columns are displayed on the layout by arranging the data in the Table window beforehand. The row and column that appear in the upper left corner of the Table window define what appears in the upper left corner of the table on the layout. As you enlarge the table frame on the layout, you'll see more rows and columns; however, the data displayed in the upper left corner does not change. ArcMap only displays an entire row or column, so a row or column does not appear until the table frame is large enough.

I think this does what you require.

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider accepting solution. This is how you say thanks.

Comment: Ie, click on the big tick (check mark) next to the answer.